# Counting repeated values in stack

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to figure out how to count repeated values in a Stack.

The code I have so far is below. I can't figure out how to store that a value has been logged once, or twice, or 100 times. 
Let's say that I have a stack of (1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 3) and I want to count how many times 1 occurs. How do I got about storing each time 1 is counted in the stack?

```
template <class Object>
int Stack<Object>::count( const Object & data ) const{
  StackNode<Object> * node = topNode;
  int n = 0;
  while (node != NULL) {
    if (data == node->getElement())
      n++;
    node = node->getNext();
  }
  return n;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have updated an altered code, still not quite right, but closer

Comment: If the range of numbers is small you can just use an array else go with a map

Comment: @Kunal Well, it is a question for a review assignment. So I think it is in general circumstances, in which I would assume the range could potentially be very large. But thank you for this suggestion

Comment: why to throw an exception if stack is empty? it sounds pretty legitimate for me, an empty stack contains 0 of any kind of elements

Comment: @AndyT Thrown exception is out of habit. It isn't necessary I suppose

Comment: Remember: Exceptions are for Exceptional circumstances. :-)

Comment: @user1158692 This is a very helpful thing to remember. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working

```
template <class Object>
int Stack<Object>::count( const Object & data ) const{
        StackNode<Object> * node = topNode;
    int n = 0;
        while (node != NULL) {
            if (data == node->getElement())
                n++;
            node = node->getNext();
        }
      return (n);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would:

1. Create a map where the key is the value you expect to find in the stack, and the value mapped is a counter
2. On each entry in the stack, look in the map above and increment the counter.

EDIT: I see that what you are trying to do is something a little different, rather than return a count of each value in the stack, you want to return a count of a specific passed in value(?)

Then you almost have it right, except that typically you cannot iterate over the contents of the stack in a normal way. So what you need to do is..

1. Pop an item from the main stack
2. If the value is the same as passed in, then count
3. Push this item into a temporary stack
4. Once the stack is empty, pop all the items from the temporary stack back into the main stack.

This means you will not require a map, but it does mean that you have to pass in the value you want to count instances of.

NOTE: This method cannot be `const` because you will need to call your `pop()` and `push()` methods of your stack class.

Comment: Note that you can increment and decrement the count at the time you push and pop stuff onto and off the stack - not at some point after a certain stack has already been established.

Comment: True, but that would require maintaining such map along with the stack, which is not clear whether is something that the OP would be interested in doing. His question, really, is just how to count the number of times a particular element appears in the stack.

Comment: Thanks,
I definitely understand the concept. But for some reason, until i've seen an example of a scenario-- in this early stage of programming, I am finding it very difficult for me connect the dots on the actual screen.

Comment: @micantox Yes count the numbers and store it in a way that I can later return the value of times the numbers were repeated in a driver file :)

Comment: @Nim This is something I'm not yet familiar with. I will try and look into this and see if I can find what I'm looking for. Thanks :-)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if we've covered maps yet in our course. So using this technique might not be the best course of action at this point

Comment: @Nim I'm almost there I can feel it! However, I am required to have this const :-/

Comment: @Nim a main issue is I'm having difficultly coding a working counting method. And just when you search around for an example of one is the very time it seems to be missing from the internet